# onchange dropdown add parameters to url in inputbox

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am designing affiliate program, in which each user has his own link-code aka tracking URL.
I am willing to add extra parameters to it depending on the drop down selection which will be different landing pages.

e.g.
original URL:

```
http://www.google.com/tracker/blah1
```

and if user selects value from down the URL should be like:

```
http://www.google.com/tracker/blah1/queryid/1
```

I am using this code for displaying the URL to the end user in the input box set as readonly.

```
<input size="100" type="text" value="<?=$url;?>" readonly> &nbsp;- &nbsp;<a  target="_blank" href="<?=$url;?>">Link</a></b>
```

There's gonna be two drop down like these.

```
<select name="niche">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="/queryid/1" label="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="/queryid/2" label="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="/queryid/3" label="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="/queryid/4" label="option 4">option 4</option>
<option value="/queryid/5" label="option 5">option 5</option>
<option value="/queryid/6" label="option 6">option 6</option>
</select>
```

By selecting <kbd>option 1</kbd> it should add **/queryid/1** to the end of the url.
if none is selected then no change will be there.

```
<select name="landingpage">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="/cid/1" label="landing 1">landing 1</option>
<option value="/cid/2" label="landing 2">landing 2</option>
</select>
```

By selecting <kbd>landing 1</kbd> will add **/cid/1** to the end of the URL.
if none is selected then no change will be there.

So how do I do this?

Update: updated the values of dropdown as currently using htaccess rewrite rules.

**update:**
I am using as specified by "Rishi Php" demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/g6U4a/2/

but by default its not showing **SourceUrl**
it should show the source URL by default, in the box but it shows it when user changes drop down values.
How can I achieve this?

**update:**
"Rishi Php" fixed the issue of on load default url.
here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/g6U4a/3/
Thanks to all of you guys.

Don't forget to add this in header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

replaced

```
var SourceUrl = "http://www.google.com/?tracker=blah1";
```

with

```
var SourceUrl = "<?=$url;?>";
```

so each affiliate will have unique link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... It 'll help. **[**UPDATED WORKING DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/g6U4a/3/)***

```
var SourceUrl = "http://www.google.com/?tracker=blah1";
var queryUrl = "";
var landingUrl = "";
$(function() {
  $('#querySelct').on('change', function () {
      if($(this).val() == 0) {
         queryUrl = "";
      } else {
          queryUrl = $(this).val();
      }
      MakeUrl();
      return false;
  });

    $('#landingSelect').on('change', function () {
      if($(this).val() == 0) {
         landingUrl = "";
      } else {
         landingUrl = $(this).val();
      }
     MakeUrl();
     return false;
  });
});

function MakeUrl() {
    var finalUrl = SourceUrl + queryUrl + landingUrl;
   $('#urlBox').val(finalUrl);
  $('#MyLink').attr('href', finalUrl);
}
```

Comment: this is working in jsfiddle but not in my website, i tried adding <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in header, still nothing, also how can i show the original url by default i meant Makeurl onlycalls when it senses change in drop down. thanks for your help .

Comment: use like this, <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> instead of "//ajax..." use like "http://.."

Comment: its working now, issue was in javascript, i didnt copied thw whole script from jsfiddle., thanks

Comment: please read the updated question, i am looking to load SourceUrl by default when page loads. its showing blank when page loads and shows the url when user changes the dropdown .

Comment: Thanks a lot, man , i really appreciate it, i am learning the code step by step, you gave me, its looks complicate than php... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use getElementById to get the values from the `<select>` fields and set them into your textfield.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/g6U4a/1/

**HTML**

```
<select id="queryid">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&queryid=1" label="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="&queryid=2" label="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="&queryid=3" label="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="&queryid=4" label="option 4">option 4</option>
<option value="&queryid=5" label="option 5">option 5</option>
<option value="&queryid=6" label="option 6">option 6</option>  
</select>

<br>

<select id="cid" name="landingpage">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&cid=1" label="landing 1">landing 1</option>
<option value="&cid=2" label="landing 2">landing 2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="change" value="Create URL" onclick="createUrl()" /><br>

<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="placeholder" readonly><br>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function createUrl() {
    var google = "http://www.google.com/";
    document.getElementById("result").value = google + document.getElementById("queryid").value +  document.getElementById("cid").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<select id="yourSelect" name="landingpage">
<option value="" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="www.yourdomain.com&cid=1" label="landing 1">landing 1</option>
<option value="www.yourdomain.com&cid=2" label="landing 2">landing 2</option>
</select>


$(function(){
  $('#yourSelect').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val();
      if (url) {
          window.location = url;
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give selector for selectbox like

```
var urlToAppend1=$('#nicheId :selected').val();

originalurl='http://www.google.com/?tracker=blah1';
var url='';
url+=originalurl;
url+=urlToAppend;
```

Comment: how exactly, i am new to javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$(function(){
        $('select').change(function() {

            var arr = new Array();
            $('select option:selected').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                if(value != "0"){
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            // selected value are now concatenating here.
            var str = arr.join('');
            alert(str);
        });

    });
```

Comment: how exactly, i am new to javascripts.

Comment: concat "str" variable with your url string and do what ever you want.
e.g. : var url = "http://www.google.com/tracker/blah1"+str;