# How do I add a submit button to go to the url I just created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created a form [Following an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629171/onchange-dropdown-add-parameters-to-url-in-inputbox)

The form creates the URL as expected and I want to add a submit button at the end in order to click and go to the new URL I just created with the form. Sorry if dumb question but im  newbie and confused... Thanks!

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/g6U4a/1/

HTML

```
<select id="queryid">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&queryid=1" label="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="&queryid=2" label="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="&queryid=3" label="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="&queryid=4" label="option 4">option 4</option>
<option value="&queryid=5" label="option 5">option 5</option>
<option value="&queryid=6" label="option 6">option 6</option>  
</select>

<br>

<select id="cid" name="landingpage">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&cid=1" label="landing 1">landing 1</option>
<option value="&cid=2" label="landing 2">landing 2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="change" value="Create URL" onclick="createUrl()" /><br>

<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="placeholder" readonly><br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function createUrl() {
var google = "http://www.google.com/";
document.getElementById("result").value = google +    document.getElementById("queryid").value +  document.getElementById("cid").value;
}
```

Comment: have a look at the `window.open` command [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go (try it in the jsfiddle, stackoverflow will block the new window):

http://jsfiddle.net/g6U4a/94/

```js
function createUrl() {
    var google = "http://www.google.com/";
    document.getElementById("result").value = google + document.getElementById("Ultra").value +  document.getElementById("landing").value;
}

function goTo(){
window.open(document.getElementById("result").value);
}
```

```css
#result {
    width:500px;
}
```

```html
<select id="Ultra"> <!--Call run() function-->
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&queryid=1" label="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="&queryid=2" label="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="&queryid=3" label="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="&queryid=4" label="option 4">option 4</option>
<option value="&queryid=5" label="option 5">option 5</option>
<option value="&queryid=6" label="option 6">option 6</option>  
</select><br><br>
<select id="landing" name="landingpage">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&cid=1" label="landing 1">landing 1</option>
<option value="&cid=2" label="landing 2">landing 2</option>
</select>


<input type="button" id="change" value="Create URL" onclick="createUrl()" /><br>
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="placeholder" ><br>
<button id="go" onclick="goTo();">Go!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer:

```
<input type="button" value="GO!" onclick="location.href = document.getElementById('result').value">
```

A bit more well-organized:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="go-btn" value="GO!">
```

**Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  location.href = document.getElementById("result").value;
});
```

If you want to open a new window with the page, simply use `window.open(document.getElementById("result").value)` instead of `location.href = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're already half way there.

If you put an extra step in your Js to just store the url and the parameters, you can then send that to a new function to show a link that the user can navigate to.

You can optionally style this link to look just like a button if you wish.

I've started the link as `visibility: hidden` until the user clicks your button the first time which will then show it.

```js
function createUrl() {
var google = "http://www.google.com/";
var params = document.getElementById("queryid").value +  document.getElementById("cid").value;

var url = google + params

document.getElementById("result").value = url
showGotoUrl(url)
}

function showGotoUrl(url) {
  var button = document.getElementById("gotoUrl");
  button.href = url;
  button.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
#result {
    width:500px;
}
```

```html
<select id="queryid">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&queryid=1" label="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="&queryid=2" label="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="&queryid=3" label="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="&queryid=4" label="option 4">option 4</option>
<option value="&queryid=5" label="option 5">option 5</option>
<option value="&queryid=6" label="option 6">option 6</option>  
</select>

<br>

<select id="cid" name="landingpage">
<option value="0" label="choose one">choose one</option>
<option value="&cid=1" label="landing 1">landing 1</option>
<option value="&cid=2" label="landing 2">landing 2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="change" value="Create URL" onclick="createUrl()" /><br>


<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="placeholder" readonly><br>

<a href="#" id="gotoUrl" style="visibility: hidden;">Go to url</a>
```